# Why is Int not promotable?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'd like to have points in two or three dimensions such that the two-dimensional points and the three-dimensional points can share code, but the compiler can tell them apart.  Here's a first attempt.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures #-}

data Dimension = D2 | D3
data Point :: Dimension -> * where
  Point :: Dimension -> [Int] -> Point d
origin = Point D2 [0, 0]
```

That works OK so far.  Here's a simplified version:

```
data Point' :: Int -> * where
  Point' :: Int -> [Int] -> Point' d
origin' = Point' 2 [0, 0]
```

This does not compile: `‘Int’ of kind ‘*’ is not promotable`.  [The documentation on datatype promotion](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/promotion.html) for GHC 7.10.3 lists various reasons that a type might not be promotable (for example, if it already involves promoted types), but I don't see why they would exclude Int.

(1) Why is it giving this error?

And as a bonus,

(2) Is there a reasonable fix or alternate approach?  A search shows, for example, [Fixed-Length Vector Types in Haskell](https://blog.jle.im/entry/fixed-length-vector-types-in-haskell.html), but that seems overcomplicated.

Comment: I recommend you stop thinking in terms of “vector lengths” entirely, and let the type system deal with [vector-_spaces_](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space) instead. Not only does this make type-level-numbers unnecessary, it also makes much better use of the type system, focusing on the _conceptual structure_ of vectors, rather than their expansion in some arbitrary basis. You can e.g. work on [spaces of linear operators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category), without any of the awkward flattening/reshaping this would require in Matlab.

Comment: Interesting, @leftaroundabout.  Any sample code around?

Comment: I use vector spaces mostly for solving differential equations, [here's one simple example](https://gist.github.com/leftaroundabout/35396046ea0a779a00cbb29c6ba76833) (numerically solving the [restricted three-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem#Circular), with a [4th order Runge-Kutta solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#The_Runge.E2.80.93Kutta_method)).

Comment: The best-known application is probably [diagrams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams), which was originally parameterised to “draw graphics in an arbitrary affine space”. (It has by now switched to the [linear library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear) – which is a bit less elegant IMO but still doesn't explicitly talk about dimensions/vector-lengths – because that apparently gives better performance in the low-dimensional case which you always have, because drawing diagrams in more than 3-dimensional space is a bit crazy...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Int` is promotable in principle, but the implementation work hasn't (yet?) been done. They are implemented at the term level as hardware words, with primitive operations implemented as C or assembly routines; each such operation one would want to use at the type level (including "convert this compile-time constant to an `Int`"!) would need to be promoted by hand, and as far as I know this hasn't been done.

Use a standard algebraic definition of numbers -- e.g. Peano nats or lists of bits -- instead, as algebraic types can be promoted with the existing implementation. Although I haven't done enough to have a recommendation for a specific one, there should be several implementations of these available on Hackage somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

While I can't speak as to why `Int` isn't promotable, I can suggest using a similar promotable type `GHC.TypeLits.Nat`. Your second example works verbatim with this definition of `Point'`

```
import GHC.TypeLits

data Point' :: Nat -> * where
    Point' :: Int -> [Int] -> Point' d
```

I'd also suggest explicitly typing `origin` or else GHC may have a difficult time inferring the type, since the `d` in `Point d` is a phantom type.

Comment: To be clear, `GHC.TypeLits.Nat` isn't really promotable in the usual sense. There is no (non-bottom) value of type `Nat`, only types of kind `Nat`. I don't think this matters to the OP, but anyways...